# 3 different storyboards for different devices programing and 3 different iAd versions

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

Hi i am having trouble with a 3.5 inch screen for my app , so i though to create another storyboard file for an iPhone 3.5 version though i already had a working iPad and iPhone 4 inch version working . My question is can there be 3 storyboards for each device ?1 for iPhone 4 inch main for 3.5 inch iphone and for iPad and how to recognize iAd height as well got it working for 2 versions iPad and iPhone but can't figure out for 3 heres the code for iAd

```
- (AppDelegate *) appdelegate {
    return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    _UIiAD = [[self appdelegate] UIiAD];
    _UIiAD.delegate = self;
    //checkts whether you are running on iPad,or iphone to get the banner to correct possition
        if ( IDIOM == IPAD ) {
            [_UIiAD setFrame:CGRectMake(0,960,320,50)];
        } else {
            [_UIiAD setFrame:CGRectMake(0,521,320,50)];

    }
    [self.view addSubview:_UIiAD];

}
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    _UIiAD.delegate = nil;
    _UIiAD=nil;
    [_UIiAD removeFromSuperview];
}

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
    NSLog(@"ads loaded");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [_UIiAD setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"ads not loaded");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [_UIiAD setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

need to do it for 3.5 as well and can't figure out 
as for the hook up about the 3 different storyboard i got this string doing it
at my plist file

Main storyboard file base name
Main storyboard file base name(iPad)
should i simply create new string 
Main storyboard file base name(iPhone)
and hook up the storyboard file i created ? 
or can anyone tell me a simpler solution maybe with constrains in Xcode 6 though i still try to figure out how it works 
thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create separate the storyboard for 3.5 inch device. just define below macros globally in your application and you can put the check for various device.

`#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)

## define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)

## define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f)

## define IS_IPHONE_4 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480.0f)

## define IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0f)

## define IDZTrace() NSLog(@"%s", **PRETTY_FUNCTION**)

`
Just put IS_IPHONE_4 check for 3.5 inch device and apply your concerning logic. You can use also use auto layout and constraints. follow http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1 if you are not clear about the constraint and auto layout concept.